# How to configure a bluetooth mouse in Windows 10 on MacBook Pro with Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, macbook, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I have a mouse (Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse) that I wish to connect to my MacBook Pro when I switch to Windows with Bootcamp. I can see the mouse when I look for devices but it stays on "Connecting" and never pairs. What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took a lot of searching, but here goes. First, cover the basics:

1. Update drivers and Windows stuff with Windows Update
2. Update Bootcamp drivers with Apple Software Update

Then, the not so subtle part:

1. Switch to Mac if your mouse is already paired there and unpair it. You can try and re-pair it later.
2. Switch to Windows, pair the mouse.
3. Reboot

If the mouse is paired, congrats. It may however turn off if you're running on the battery. That's **power management** throwing one last monkey wrench in the works.

For this, go in the Device Manager, open Bluetooth then Bluetooth radio, open its properties, go in the Power Management tab and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power."

[image]

Comment: Great find! Power management was killing my bluetooth connectivity on bootcamp. Also found it useful to [install the Microsoft Drivers found here for customizing the default buttons](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center)